# I cannot querySelect input of ion-searchbar in Jasmine tests

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic4

I'm running a simple test - enter a value into an Ionic search bar.
I cannot get a reference to the search bar input field in my jasmine tests.

I've set up a simple vanilla Ionic 4 app with a single test page.
The following tests all fail.

```
const el: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
const input = el.querySelector('input');
expect(input).not.toBeNull();  // FAILS 

const bar = el.querySelector('ion-searchbar');
expect(bar.innerHTML).not.toEqual(''); // FAILS
expect(bar.shadowRoot).not.toBeNull();  // FAILS
```

I don't understand why?
I've written other tests successfully on Ionic lists to read values.
I tried putting in timers to give the component time to render the html.
If I put a simple HTML input field on the page it is picked up OK.
I thought the shadow DOM might be relevant here even though when I inspect the input field in the browser it doesn't seem to be in the shadow DOM, and the standard document.querySelector works just fine.

HTML Page

```
// test.page.html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Test Page
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
</ion-content>
```

Component Class

```
// test.page.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.page.scss'],
})
export class TestPage {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Test Spec

```
// test.page.spec.ts
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TestPage } from './test.page';

describe('TestPage', () => {
  let component: TestPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestPage>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestPage ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    })
    .compileComponents();

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should have a searchbar', () => {
    const el: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const bar = el.querySelector('ion-searchbar');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(bar).not.toBeNull();             // PASSES
    // adding some checks to see what is going on 
    expect(bar.children.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);  // FAILS
    expect(bar.innerHTML).not.toEqual('');  // FAILS
    expect(bar.shadowRoot).not.toBeNull();  // FAILS
  });

  it('should have an input field', () => {
    const el: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const input = el.querySelector('input');
    expect(input).not.toBeNull();           // FAILS
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is over a year late, but I think it's worth answering for others who might need it. For what it's worth, I'm running @ionic-native/core 4.15 with @angular/core 5.2.11 and ionic-angular 3.9.2.

I don't know why `const input = el.querySelector('input');` isn't working for you. The following code works for me:

```
const toolbar = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('ion-toolbar')
const searchBar = toolbar.querySelector('ion-searchbar');
const input = searchBar.querySelector('input');
```

Alternatively, you can make your query for the input more specific:

```
const input = searchBar.querySelector('div.searchbar-input-container > input.searchbar-input')
```

I like to look at the structure of HTMLElements and their component instances by `console.log`ing them in the test. When I add this to my test:

```
console.log(searchBar);
```

The console in the captured test browser will output:

```
<ion-searchbar class="searchbar searchbar-md searchbar-left-aligned" ng-reflect-placeholder="Besmirch">
    <div class="searchbar-input-container">
        <button class="searchbar-md-cancel button button-md button-clear button-clear-md button-clear-md-dark" clear="" color="dark" ion-button="" mode="md" type="button" ng-reflect-color="dark" ng-reflect-mode="md" ng-reflect-clear=""><span class="button-inner"><ion-icon name="md-arrow-back" role="img" class="icon icon-md" aria-label="arrow back" ng-reflect-name="md-arrow-back"></ion-icon></span>
            <div class="button-effect"></div>
        </button>
        <div class="searchbar-search-icon"></div>
        <input class="searchbar-input" dir="auto" placeholder="Besmirch" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
        <button class="searchbar-clear-icon button button-md button-clear button-clear-md" clear="" ion-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-mode="md" ng-reflect-clear=""><span class="button-inner"></span>
            <div class="button-effect"></div>
        </button>
    </div>
    <button class="searchbar-ios-cancel button button-ios button-clear button-clear-ios" clear="" ion-button="" mode="ios" type="button" ng-reflect-mode="ios" ng-reflect-clear="" tabindex="-1"><span class="button-inner">Cancel</span>
        <div class="button-effect"></div>
    </button>
</ion-searchbar>
```

In this structure, we can see the input is in the `.searchbar-input-container` div.